# python, if line.startswith("word") check the 20th line and print

Tags: python

I am trying to go through a file. If the line starts with "SegID", I want to look at the 21st line after it and if that line starts with anything other than "Cytoplasmic", I want to write the line starting the SegID and the line starting with anything but "Cytoplasmic" to a file.

So far, i have this:

```
import sys
import argparse
import operator
import re
import itertools

def main (argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='find a location')
    parser.add_argument('infile', help='file to process')
    parser.add_argument('outfile', help='file to produce')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    tag = "SeqID:"
    tag2 = "Cytoplasmic"

    with open(args.infile, "r") as f,open(args.outfile,"w+") as of:
        file_in = f.readlines()
        for line in file_in:
            if line.startswith(tag)and line[21:] != "Cytoplasmic":
                 of.write(line)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.arg
```

Here is an example of the input file:

```
SeqID: YP_008914846.1 opacity protein [Neisseria gonorrhoeae FA 1090]
  Analysis Report:
    CMSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    CytoSVM-          Unknown                       [No details]
    ECSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    ModHMM-           Unknown                       [No internal helices found]
    Motif-            Unknown                       [No motifs found]
    OMPMotif-         Unknown                       [No motifs found]
    OMSVM-            OuterMembrane                 [No details]
    PPSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    Profile-          Unknown                       [No matches to profiles found]
    SCL-BLAST-        OuterMembrane                 [matched 60392864: Opacity protein opA54 precursor]
    SCL-BLASTe-       Unknown                       [No matches against database]
    Signal-           Unknown                       [No signal peptide detected]
  Localisation Scores:
    OuterMembrane          10.00
    Extracellular          0.00
    Periplasmic            0.00
    Cytoplasmic            0.00
    CytoplasmicMembrane    0.00
  Final Prediction:
    OuterMembrane          10.00

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SeqID: YP_008914847.1 hypothetical protein NGO0146a [Neisseria gonorrhoeae FA 1090]
  Analysis Report:
    CMSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    CytoSVM-          Unknown                       [No details]
    ECSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    ModHMM-           Unknown                       [No internal helices found]
    Motif-            Unknown                       [No motifs found]
    OMPMotif-         Unknown                       [No motifs found]
    OMSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    PPSVM-            Unknown                       [No details]
    Profile-          Unknown                       [No matches to profiles found]
    SCL-BLAST-        Unknown                       [No matches against database]
    SCL-BLASTe-       Unknown                       [No matches against database]
    Signal-           Unknown                       [No signal peptide detected]
  Localization Scores:
    CytoplasmicMembrane    2.00
    Cytoplasmic            2.00
    OuterMembrane          2.00
    Periplasmic            2.00
    Extracellular          2.00
  Final Prediction:
    Unknown
```

---

Comment: So, what actually is the question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I dont seem to be able to get the final prediciton

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the desired output please?

Comment: The output just prints out the line starting with SegID

Comment: Sorry, i would like to get something like this:                 SeqID: YP_008914846.1 opacity protein [Neisseria gonorrhoeae FA 1090]

    OuterMembrane          10.00

Comment: Do you mean SeqID? I don't see SegID.

Comment: SeqID: YP_008914846.1 opacity protein [Neisseria gonorrhoeae FA 1090]

    OuterMembrane          10.00

Comment: yes, sorry typo

Comment: What do you think the condition `line[21:] != "Cytoplasmic"` does? It checks the 22nd character in the line, not 21 lines after the current one, right?

Comment: I wanted to say if the 21st line doesnt start with the word cytoplasmic. Ok. how do I ask it to check the 21st line after the SeqId line?

Comment: Please provide the desired output for the given input

Comment: The output I would like  -                                               SeqID: YP_008914846.1 opacity protein [Neisseria gonorrhoeae FA 1090]                                        OuterMembrane 10.00. I am trying to provide the outupur. I just want the SeqID line and the final prediction line printed.

Comment: Well, then just print the first line and and last line.

Comment: I cant, Its a long file that has 1000th of lines. I need to check this for every SeqID. I need to check every 21st line after each SeqID incidence

Comment: Well. Is the offset fixed? Then you can just iterate over the file.

Comment: I am trying, I just dont seem be able to do so. The offset if fixed, I am asking for a help with the code. I know theoretically very well what to do

Comment: Any chance of anyone giving an actual code advice?

Comment: Well Loki, I can hack up some code, probably not the best code if you wish.

Comment: That would be great! I just cant figure out how to iterate:) I am on it for several hours:(

Answer (score 1):

My Python is a bit rusty, so, please be forgiving. I hope I extrapolated correctly the desired output, comment otherwise please.

This assumes that the samples from your sequencing experiment are separated always by 3 lines offset of arbitrary content, and each sample has 22 lines.

```
import re

def extract_data(filename):
  numLinesToSkip = 3
  offset = 22
  seqIdLineNumber = 0
  predictionLineNumber = 21
  with open(filename, "r") as f:
      output = []
      while True:
        try: head = [next(f) for x in xrange(offset)]
        except StopIteration: break
        line21 = re.split(r'\s+',head[predictionLineNumber].strip())
        sample = head[seqIdLineNumber].rstrip() + "\t" + " ".join(line21)
        output.append(sample)
        try: [next(f) for x in xrange(numLinesToSkip)]
        except StopIteration: break
      print "\n".join(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  extract_data("test.txt")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Unfortunately, I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "psortb.py", line 20, in <module>
    extract_data("PSortb.txt")
  File "psortb.py", line 11, in extract_data
    head = [next(f) for x in xrange(offset)]
StopIteration

Comment: Strange, I used your input from above, and this worked for me. You have more data? This works only if your file ends not with a 3 line separator though. Edited to work now.

Comment: I think that is working, thank you very much! I will have a proper how youd did this and learn from it. Thank you

Comment: Maybe try also to learn from the other users, because as I said my Python is not the best. :) (Also it took 3 minutes only to bring it up)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use something like:

```
    with open('credentials.json', "r") as f:
        file_in = f.readlines()
        for i,line in enumerate(file_in):

            if line.startswith(tag) and \
                    (i+21)< len(file_in) and \ 
                    not(file_in[i+21].strip().startswith("Cytoplasmic")):
                of.write(line)
                of.write(file_in[i+21])
```

Comment: This does not account for the offset, but interesting approach.

Comment: It is doing the `strip()` which should remove all the offset. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, not all lines are empty, one would have to account for this.

Comment: This is interesting, how could I account for the offset here?

Comment: Maybe do something like this: file_in = [line for line in f.readlines() if not line.startswith("-")]. Note that the file will be read at once into memory, which might be a problem if you have a *very large* file.

Comment: But the description says `line starting with anything but "Cytoplasmic" to a file.`. I think this we should not remove those kind of lines, do we? @Loki could you try to run this solution on your dataset?

Comment: @ymochurad: Yes, did you see the comments in the OP's original post? He stated the desired output there.

Comment: ymochurad, I did run this but it only writes the lines starting with SeqID. I dont think it recognises the 21st line.

Comment: Right, added the output for twenty first line also